# how do i display afterpay and klarna payment options on my footer of my shopify website,? i cant find it anywhere

Tags: icons, shopify, footer, payment, gateway

***Hi everyone,
I want to be able to add my payment options at the bottom of my website in the footer, such as afterpay, klarna. However i can't find even an option anywhere in my back end to enable payment icons to my footer. Can someone please help me?
i have tried looking for these options and i have tried editing my footer but i can't seem to find the problem.
how do i display afterpay and klarna payment options on my footer of my shopify website as i can't find it anywhere.***

Comment: You need to check your theme for this, every theme handle payment icons into different way.

Comment: If you can't find it, maybe you can add it manually, you can use this tool: https://ui-elements-generator.myshopify.com/pages/methods-of-payment -- (you would still need to add klarna manually though)

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you activate them as payment options, they should automatically show in the footer with the other payment icons.